# Uncontrollable displacement in positioning pst-optexp component

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I am beginner in pst-opexp and I have a problem with positioning component. When I try no draw a lens in the position (2,1) (see code after), I get a lens in the position (1.92,1) (see figure). The gap of almost 0.08 unit annoys me.
Does anyone have an explanation or, even better, a solution?
Thank you very much.
The code I use is

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,2.3)
  \pnodes(0,1){A}(4,1){B}
  \lens[abspos=2](A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: @eamy: Compiling your code (latex,dvips,ps2pdf) with `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{pst-optexp}` produces a correct output on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Please update your TeX-Distribution, then it should work. It is a trailing space in `showgirl`

[image]

Comment: `showgirl` :). A new option probably.

Comment: uhh ... ;-) Don't know what I had in mind :-)